# Differentiable function to find a+b

Tags: calculus, functions

Let function $f(x)= \begin{cases}ax^3+2, &x<\dfrac 12 \\ bx^2+1, & x\ge \dfrac 12\end{cases}$. If the function is differentiable at $x=\dfrac 12$, then $a+b=$???

Comment: What is happening as that function approaches 1/2 from the left and from the right?  It is continous at 1/2?  Is the derivative defined at 1/2?  What are the tests?  For what values of $a,b$ might $f(x)$ pass the tests.

Comment: It is differentiable iff the left derivative equals the right derivative iff 3ax^2=2bx (when x=1) iff 3a=2b iff a=2b/3 iff a+b=5b/3

Comment: @Alephnull there's more than just the derivative from each side. It must also be continuous

Comment: @CurtisBechtel Oh of course. Now we have two equations.

Answer (score 0):

$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
ax^3+2  & \text{x<1/2} \\[2ex]
bx^2+1, & \text{x≥1/2}
\end{cases}$

$f(n)' =
\begin{cases}
3ax^2  & \text{left derivative 1/2} \\[2ex]
2bx, & \text{right derivative in 1/2}
\end{cases}$

If f is differentiable at a point x, then f must also be continuous at x.
Since v(x) is a continuous function, then the limit as x approaches t is equal to the value of v(x) at x = t

$\begin{cases}
3a(1/2)^2=b(1/2)^2+1  & \text{left derivative at 1/2} \\[2ex]
2b(1/2)=b(1/2)^2+1, & \text{right derivative at 1/2}
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
a(3/4)=b(1/4)+1  & \text{}\\[2ex]
(1-1/4)b=1, & \text{}
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
a=16/9& \text{}\\[2ex]
b=4/3, & \text{}
\end{cases}$

$a+b=28/9$